# jQuery DateTimePicker Not displaying the first time field gets focus

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have developed a web application that uses the jQuery DateTimePicker by Trent Richardson 
(see http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)

This is a C# aps.net app, that has a field called tbDate, because I have a MasterPage, this field is known as #MainContent_tbDate to jQuery.

In the backend C# code the following line has been added to the PagePreRenderComplete event.

```
 tbDate.Attributes.Add("onFocus", "getDate('#MainContent_tbDate');");
```

This as you can see simply adds an onFocus event to the field. (This works for 12 other fields)

In my .js file I have the following code.

```
    //This function launches the date picker
    function getDate(field){
        if (debug)
            {
                $.jGrowl("Displaying Date for field " + field);
            }
            $(field).datetimepicker({
                dateFormat:'dd/mm/yy',
                timeFormat:'hh:mm'
             });
        if (debug) {
            $.jGrowl("Launched " + field);
        }
    }
```

This is run when the field gets focus.  Now the issue is the first time it does get focus I see my first jGrowl message, Then NO Date Picker, then I see my second jGrowl message.

I get no Scripting errors.

If I take focus away from the field and then give it back I see the date picker correctly.

Why don't I see it the first time the field gets focus?????

Thanks

SM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
function getDate(field){
      $(function(){ 
         if (debug)
            {
                $.jGrowl("Displaying Date for field " + field);
            }
            $(field).datetimepicker({
                dateFormat:'dd/mm/yy',
                timeFormat:'hh:mm'
             });
        if (debug) {
            $.jGrowl("Launched " + field);
        }
}) 
    }
```

Comment: This fix it in IE8, however the issue still appears in Chrome, on both a Mac and Windows XP.